Tab widget arrows disabled for seemingly no reason
I don't disable my tab widget arrows in my code, yet the arrows are always disabled. why might this be?

I am using PySide6 on windows 10. Here's the minimal code to recreate the problem:
generated PySide6 code from qtDesigner: "frmSetupDialog_copy_ui.py"
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'frmSetupDialog_copy.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 6.7.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QFrame, QGridLayout,
    QHBoxLayout, QLayout, QPushButton, QSizePolicy,
    QTabWidget, QWidget)

class Ui_SetupDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, SetupDialog):
        if not SetupDialog.objectName():
            SetupDialog.setObjectName(u"SetupDialog")
        SetupDialog.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)
        SetupDialog.resize(1024, 560)
        SetupDialog.setMinimumSize(QSize(1024, 560))
        SetupDialog.setMaximumSize(QSize(1024, 560))
        SetupDialog.setStyleSheet(u"#setup_frame{ border: 2px solid black; }")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(SetupDialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setup_frame = QFrame(SetupDialog)
        self.setup_frame.setObjectName(u"setup_frame")
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.setup_frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.setup_frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.setup_frame.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 650))
        self.setup_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.setup_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.gridLayout_24 = QGridLayout(self.setup_frame)
        self.gridLayout_24.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_24")
        self.horizontalLayout_12 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_12.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_12")
        self.horizontalLayout_12.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.btn_ok = QPushButton(self.setup_frame)
        self.btn_ok.setObjectName(u"btn_ok")
        sizePolicy1 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_ok.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_ok.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1)
        self.btn_ok.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 45))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(27)
        self.btn_ok.setFont(font)

        self.horizontalLayout_12.addWidget(self.btn_ok)

        self.btn_cancel = QPushButton(self.setup_frame)
        self.btn_cancel.setObjectName(u"btn_cancel")
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_cancel.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_cancel.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1)
        self.btn_cancel.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 45))
        font1 = QFont()
        font1.setPointSize(24)
        self.btn_cancel.setFont(font1)

        self.horizontalLayout_12.addWidget(self.btn_cancel)


        self.gridLayout_24.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_12, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self.setup_frame)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(u"tabWidget")
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 9))
        self.tabWidget.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        font2 = QFont()
        font2.setPointSize(20)
        self.tabWidget.setFont(font2)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet(u"QTabBar::scroller { /* the width of the scroll buttons */\n"
"    width: 130px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"/*QTabBar QToolButton { /* the scroll buttons are tool buttons */\n"
"/*    width: 15px;\n"
"    border-width: 2px;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.tab_8 = QWidget()
        self.tab_8.setObjectName(u"tab_8")
        self.gridLayout_20 = QGridLayout(self.tab_8)
        self.gridLayout_20.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_20")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_8, "")
        self.tab_3 = QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName(u"tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_7 = QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_7.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_7")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_2 = QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(u"tab_2")
        self.gridLayout_12 = QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout_12.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_12")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_6 = QWidget()
        self.tab_6.setObjectName(u"tab_6")
        self.gridLayout_22 = QGridLayout(self.tab_6)
        self.gridLayout_22.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_22")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_6, "")
        self.tab_7 = QWidget()
        self.tab_7.setObjectName(u"tab_7")
        self.gridLayout_11 = QGridLayout(self.tab_7)
        self.gridLayout_11.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_11")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_7, "")
        self.tab_9 = QWidget()
        self.tab_9.setObjectName(u"tab_9")
        self.gridLayout_8 = QGridLayout(self.tab_9)
        self.gridLayout_8.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_8")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_9, "")
        self.tab_5 = QWidget()
        self.tab_5.setObjectName(u"tab_5")
        self.gridLayout_15 = QGridLayout(self.tab_5)
        self.gridLayout_15.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_15")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_5, "")
        self.tab_4 = QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName(u"tab_4")
        self.gridLayout_19 = QGridLayout(self.tab_4)
        self.gridLayout_19.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_19")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.tab = QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(u"tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")

        self.gridLayout_24.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 1, 0, 1, 1)


        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.setup_frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)


        self.retranslateUi(SetupDialog)

        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(8)


        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SetupDialog)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, SetupDialog):
        SetupDialog.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("SetupDialog", u"Dialog", None))
        self.btn_ok.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("SetupDialog", u"Save", None))
        self.btn_cancel.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("SetupDialog", u"Cancel", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_8), QCoreApplication.translate("SetupDialog", u"example tab", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), QCoreApplication.translate("SetupDialog", u"example tab", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), QCoreApplication.translate("SetupDialog", u"example tab", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_6), QCoreApplication.translate("SetupDialog", u"example tab", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_7), QCoreApplication.translate("SetupDialog", u"example tab", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_9), QCoreApplication.translate("SetupDialog", u"example tab", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_5), QCoreApplication.translate("SetupDialog", u"example tab", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), QCoreApplication.translate("SetupDialog", u"example tab", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), QCoreApplication.translate("SetupDialog", u"example tab", None))
    # retranslateUi

PySide6 code for running application:
from frmSetupDialog_copy_ui import Ui_SetupDialog
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

class MinimalSetup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, tab_select='Admin_Access'):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_SetupDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
        
        for tab in range(9):
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(tab, False)
        
        if tab_select == 'View_Only':
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(4, True)
            self.ui.btn_ok.setVisible(False)
            self.ui.btn_cancel.setText('Close')
            
        elif tab_select == 'User_Access': 
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(0, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(1, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(3, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(4, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(6, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(7, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
            
        elif tab_select == 'Admin_Access':
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(0, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(1, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(3, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(4, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(5, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(6, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setTabVisible(7, True)
            self.ui.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)

        self.show()
        
app = QApplication([])
window = MinimalSetup()
app.exec()

I looked through all my code and stylesheets and could not find a place where I disabled the ToolButton for the TabWidget. But who knows, I may just be overlooking something.
As you might've noticed in the MinimalSetup class, I make all the tabs invisible, then make certain tabs visible again based on the level of access. Might this be the cause of the problem?

The disabling of the arrows is correct, since you set the visibility of the overflow tabs to false. Thus, there is nothing to scroll to.

yes, I set the visibility to the tabs to false, but then I set them back to visible before the window is shown. So there is something to scroll to (at least for the user and admin access levels).

Probably the same bug for this post, it was reported but unfortunately the author used the wrong PYSIDE tag and never cared to properly report it as a QTBUG.

@Isaac So you are doing something to disable the arrows - it's not happening for "no reason". Your question asks why that might be, which my comment explained. The real issue here is that making a subset of the tabs visible again isn't handled properly  - which is caused by a bug in Qt. A simple work-around for this is to keep an internal list of (page, text) and then completely clear and re-populate the tabs instead of toggling their visibility. This will ensure Qt doesn't lose track of how many visible tabs there are and/or their logical positions.
